# Not Found error while loading internal JSON file in Chrome Extension with qTip2 plugin

Tags: jquery, json, google-chrome-extension, qtip2

I am building a simple Chrome extension for my website and I am using qTip2 tooltip jquery plugin with the extension.

I'm trying to populate the content of the Tooltip using data from a JSON file, but I keep getting a "Not Found" error within the body of the Tooltip.

The als.json file is located in the 'src' folder within the Chrome Extension.  I'm also unsure of the JSON file's formatting in this scenario.

Here is the JS for the tooltip that is injected by the Chrome extension.

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {     
 $('div.row.entry').each(function() {
     $(this).qtip({
        content: {
                    text: 'Loading...', // Loading text...
                    ajax: {
                        url: '/src/als.json', // URL to the JSON script
                        type: 'GET', // POST or GET
                        data: {}, // Data to pass along with your request
                        dataType: 'json', // Tell it we're retrieving JSON
                        success: function(data) {


                            var content = 'Description: ' + data.Entry_Type1.Description;
                            this.set('content.text', content);

                            // Now we set the content manually (required!)

                        },
                        error: function() {
                            this.set('content.text', "error");
                        }

                    }
                },
        position: {
    target: 'mouse',
adjust: { mouse: false }
        },
        style: 'qtip-wiki'
     });
 });
 });
```

And here is the JSON file:

```
{
"Entry_Type1": {
    "typeID": "01",
     "Description": "01 Blah Blah Blah." 

       },

"Entry_Type2": {
    "typeID": "02",
    "Description": "02 Blah Blah Blah." 

       },

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I needed to add the JSON file to the manifest.json under:

"web_accessible_resources": ["src/als.json"]

and then in the javascript that I was injecting, to call the JSON file with:

chrome.extension.getURL('src/als.json')